# Gazebo amcl_pose rate

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, amcl-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running a turtlebot in Gazebo and want to change the amcl_pose rate. Currently, when I type `rostopic hz /amcl_pose`, I get 1 or 2 messages like the following every 1 second:

```
average rate: 1.856
    min: 0.132s max: 0.849s std dev: 0.14089s window: 80
```

Is there a way to increase this rate?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243598/gazebo-amcl_pose-rate/) by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, the `amcl_pose` rate doesn't have to be that fast. Cuz `odom_pose` rate is 10Hz to 50Hz, which is continuous. The duty of `amcl_pose` is to fix the odometry drift.

While I guess you can still change the `amcl_pose` rate by tuning the parameters of `amcl`. You can go to [amcl wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) for details. You may tune the max_particles, update_min_d or other parameters, but it hard to change the rate directly, in my opinion.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on 2016-09-13**:
Thank you!